# How to make update function check if it has loaded same context as there already is?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

So I have next update function:

```
 function update() {
        var xmlhttp;
        try {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            var success = false;
            var objects = ["MSXML2.XMLHTTP.5.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.4.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"];
            for (var i = 0; i < objects.length && !success; i++) {
                try {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject(objects[i]);
                    success = true;
                } catch (e) { };
            }
            if (!success) throw new Error("AJAX is unavailabe");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                document.getElementById('usersList').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            };
        }
        xmlhttp.open("get", "buttons.html", true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
    update();
    setInterval(update, 5000);
```

so what I want it not to update documents contents if it has loaded same stuff that there is already. How to do such thing?

Comment: Well that depends, what does your response text look like? If it is just text, instead of saying document.getElementById('usersList').innerHTML, return the responseText which you will store in a variable. Then compare that with the text that is already in usersList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do the download first to determine what text you're comparing in the first place. I'm assuming `buttons.html` is somehow dynamic, so when you download it, you need to compare it to what's already in the `innerHTML` of `userList`.

```
    ...
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            if(document.getElementById('usersList').innerHTML != xmlhttp.responseText)
                document.getElementById('usersList').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        };
    }
    ...
```

In addition, if you're going to do a lot of ajax, I suggest using a library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). Ajax calls are as simple as

```
 $('#userList').load('buttons.html');
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'buttons.html',
    success: function(data) {
        if ($('#userList').html() != data)
            $('#userList').html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Trouble with `!=` is that the browser may make changes to the HTML structure. For example, if the original markup included a `<table>` without a `<tbody>`, the browser will insert it.

Comment: You may be right that it would be acceptable to overwrite, but the question was how to not overwrite with the same original HTML. I'd think it would be better to find a way to not send the request in the first place.

Comment: Yes.. the IDEAL solution is to keep track in the user database a time when the last change was made (user login, user logoff, etc..). Then, `buttons.html` should check the date against the user's last check and do some logic, only returning data if data needs to be updated.

Comment: @patrick, good point... Then may be store the previous response, and compare it to the new.

Comment: @Mic: Good thinkin'. :o) You should answerify that.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && 
    document.getElementById('usersList').innerHTML != xmlhttp.responseText) {
  document.getElementById('usersList').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
};
```

**EDIT:** After patrick's comment in the page, it looks better to store the response somewhere and compare it to the new instead of relying on the `innerHTML` that can change the original HTML string.